# How do I re-order list items depending on the screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to re-order the HTML list when the screen size falls below 767px. So far I have the below HTML which is required for desktop. However, how do I re-order this to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 etc using JQuery or Vanilla Javascript?

```
<ul class="path">
    <li>111</li>
    <li>222</li>
    <li>333</li>
    <li>666</li>
    <li>555</li>
    <li>444</li>
    <li>777</li>
    <li>888</li>
    <li>999</li>                                  
<ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ( $(window).width() < 768 ){
        // ORDER 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 8 9 etc

        }
        else{
        // ORDER 1 2 3 6 5 4 7 8 9

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose behind doing this?

Comment: Push the values to an array and replace the contents of the li elements with the dynamically ordered array items. Don't need jQuery for this - a simple array.reverse() will suffice

Comment: I have a path of steps which snake from the left, 1,2,3 then underneath 4, 5, 6 from the right etc. However, on mobile when each li is 100%, due to the order of the HTML it will show as 1,2,3,6,5,4 and this will be incorrect.